# how to embed a movie clip in a SWF using transform jar (flagstone)

Tags: java, video, flash, transform

I have been stuck since past 2 days in one small issue. I'm trying to create a movie from images & the movie will have separate starting & ending images. The sound will start after the first image and will continue before the end image. According to the length of the sound the intermediate images (total number not fixed) are set to a framerate. I want to have the first & last image of specific fixed duration and the intermediate images depending on the length of the audio. Now since the frame-rate is decided by the length of the sound, larger the length implies smaller framerate and hence large time for the first & last time. In order to solve this issue, I thought that I should create a separate movie clip (for the starting & end image) and add to the original movie. But I'm unable to do so ? Please let me know how to add a movie clip to the main movie. I'm using transform api from flagstone.

Comment: I assume that you dont' have the .fla source file I'm I right?

Comment: Which .fla are you referring to ? I don't have any .fla ? Transform API is a API in java using which I can create .swf files. I guess you're assuming that I'm using flex/actionscript but no I'm using the Transform Java API.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this app, I found out this [link](http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2229) It doesn't look like an easy task to do. Perhaps You could use a swf decompiler and try to embed the swf. Good luck!